# How to keep button state across different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do a click, I assign a `disabled attribute` to the button:

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
});
```

However, if I change page and then I go back to this one, the button should keep the disabled attribute given, this is fine if I use localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("savedArticle", "savedButton");
var myButtonState = localStorage.getItem("savedArticle", "savedButton");
$(".save_post").addClass(myButtonState);
```

However, I have different pages which can have `<button type="button" class="save_post">SAVE</button>` so each time I click on a button, a `disabled attribute` is given, but if I use the `localStorage` like above, it will add `myButtonState` to all buttons with class `.save_post` each time we land on a page with it.

I am trying to add the attribute only to the buttons really clicked.

Comment: Use `id` instead?

Comment: @BenM mm maybe that's actually an idea, so generate a new ID each time we land on a page and save that id and then add the attribute based on that?

Comment: How do you wish to save these states for each page? Database? Cookies? May need a more complete example. Do these buttons have an ID?

Comment: Well if they all have to be separate than you have to set each one. How? an array of individual records in storage.... really tons of ways

Comment: @Twisty i don't want cookie nor database, localStorage would be fine

Comment: @rob.m No, give each `.save_post` button an `id` (that's unique, of course), and when the user clicks it, add the `id` attribute to local storage. Then just use `$('#'+buttonID).attr('disbaled', true)`.

Comment: @epascarello so basically `localStorage.setItem("savedArticle", $('myID').attr('disabled', 'true'));`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better behavior to set the button disabled by default and enable it only when the users make changes to the form/page/input fields?

Comment: @BenM and to set the localStorage value I'd do what I wrote on previous comment, right?

Comment: @rob.m if you will use `localStorage` then I would advise you get the state of each button (and it's ID), and create an Object to store all this in and then store that object in `localStorage` for the page, or a reference to the page. This way you can unpack this when the page loads, and reset the state of each button on the page.

Comment: @Twisty yes exactly, got it. Also the answer helped with a real example.

Comment: @AnthonyC nope, it's a `save button`, so is enabled by default and disabled once you click on it. It's written in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign an ID to each `.save_post` element:

```
<button id="savePost1" class="save_post">Save Post</button>
```

And then reference the ID:

```
$('.save_post').on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
    localStorage.setItem('saveButton', $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And then call it on load:

```
$('#'+localStorage.getItem('saveButton')).attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: superb yes, makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot. Will accept in a minute

Comment: @rob.m The only issue is if the user is able to click multiple `.save_post` buttons.

Comment: they won't be able to as I am setting the disable attribute as soon as they click on it, so the button is disabled right after they click, not just saving the state in localStorage

Comment: or i could simply add it as an array list and make the array unique but that's complicating for no reasons unless you remove the attribute disabled manually form the html

Comment: actually there is a problem tho, by doing this, we are always replacing the savedId, we should add them as an array as we will add many ids as we have many pages

Comment: Then just store a JSON array string in local storage instead, and use that.

Comment: this is how i resolved it     `var curPostId = $(".my_post_id").attr("data-id");

    if(localStorage.getItem("lines")) {
      if (lines.includes(curPostId)) {
        $('#_'+curPostId).attr('disabled', true);
      }
    }`