# How to check if localStorage value is in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867599/jquery-inarray-how-to-use-it-right) I should be using `$.inArray`, therefore I do:

```
var curPostId = $(".my_post_id").attr("data-id");

if($.inArray(curPostId, lines)) {
  $('#'+localStorage.getItem('saveButton')).attr('disabled', true);
}
```

If I do: console.log(curPostId); I get `248` which is correct. Then if I do `console.log(lines);` I get `[242, 248]`

Lines is defined like this:

```
var lines = localStorage.getItem("lines") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")) : [];
```

But the check if it's in Array doesn't happen as this it's not applied `$('#'+localStorage.getItem('saveButton')).attr('disabled', true);`

This is how I set daveButton on local storage

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
  if (counter >= 2) { 
    alert('nope'); 
    return; 
  } else {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
    localStorage.setItem('saveButton', $(this).attr('id'));
    var thisId = $(".my_post_id").attr("data-id");
    lines.push(thisId);
    localStorage.setItem("lines", JSON.stringify(lines));
  }
});
```

This question is a follow up to my previous question [how to keep button state across different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561164/how-to-keep-button-state-across-different-pages?noredirect=1#comment86130544_49561164) which has an answer that works but only partly.

Comment: Might you simply use the built-in method `Array.includes` instead? (it's less of a misnomer than `inArray`, and more closely matches what you're trying to do)

Comment: @CertainPerformance hello, yes I will try now, thanks

Comment: @CertainPerformance actually could you post a link? I only find inArray even when i look for include

Comment: For example `if (lines.includes(curPostId))`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Seems like it is working, I will double check and then ask you for an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: `$.inArray` return index of element so what happens is, your element is at '0' th index and if condition returns false if value is 0

Comment: I see what you mea @Kenny thanks

Comment: That's not a duplicate of what was suggested. This one is more about arrays than checking if a property is in `localStorage`, which is why I voted for reopening.

Comment: @acdcjunior exactly, thanks for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `Array.includes` method instead - it's less confusing, more appropriately matches what you're looking for, and doesn't require jQuery.

```
if (lines.includes(curPostId)) {
  // ...
```

Also note that you can simplify your syntax by assigning and getting from `localStorage`'s dot properties directly, for example:

```
var lines = JSON.parse(localStorage.lines || '[]');
// ... 
localStorage.saveButton = $(this).attr('id');
// ... 
localStorage.lines = JSON.stringify(lines);
```

Comment: I just copied that from your line `localStorage.setItem('saveButton', $(this).attr('id'));`, which you can replace with dot notation if you want to make your code easier to read with less syntax noise.

Comment: `localStorage.saveButton = $(this).attr('id');` shouldn't it be a push? Otherwise  each time we land on a page this will be replaced

Comment: `var saveButton = [];` then on a click         `saveButton.push($(this).attr('id'));` ?

Comment: actually the array should be set like i do for lines `var saveButton = localStorage.getItem("saveButton") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saveButton")) : [];` correct?

Comment: I didn't look at what the code was doing there, I just copied it and converted it into dot notation. But it looks like `saveButton` is intended to be a string, not an array?

Comment: actually i probably don't even need saveButton, based on the code in the question i do  `var lines = localStorage.getItem("lines") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")) : [];` and I save the ids on a click and push them into it and i get an array like `[242, 248`], so i suppose by simply doing     `if (lines.includes(curPostId)) {
      $('#'+curPostId).attr('disabled', true);
    }` would be fine?

Comment: matter of fact if I do     `if (lines.includes(curPostId)) {
      console.log("hello");
      $('#'+curPostId).attr('disabled', true);
    }` I get `hello` yet the `attribute` is not set, is `$('#'+curPostId).attr('disabled', true);` correct ?

Comment: mm nope, i should be getting the matching value as use that for `$('#'+ID).` so how do I grab the matching value?

Comment: I was only describing a better array method (and a better way of using localStorage), I have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish here. If you have another question feel free to post it, but comments aren't the right place for that.

Comment: I am trying to resolve this answer, because the given solution works but only with a single id, but each time i land on page i add an id, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49561288/1018804

Answer (score 1):

$.inArray return index of element so what happens is, your element is at '0' th index and if condition will be false if value is 0

So you can use

```
 if($.inArray(curPostId, lines) !== -1) {
```

or Use `includes` method of ES6

```
if (lines.includes(curPostId)) {
```

Comment: yup, this works, had to accept the other answer as it was firstly suggested on a comment. But the principle is the same and this answer is correct too. Thanks